# Как найти сразу все буквы латинского алфавита и удалить их в Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Как найти сразу все буквы латинского алфавита и удалить их в Notepad++

Есть документ с английскими и русскими словами. Мне необходимо удалить все английские слова и цифры, чтоб остались только русские слова. очень неудобно искать и удалять по одной букве.

"a" → "заменить всё" → "/0"

"b" → "заменить всё" → "/0"

"c" → "заменить всё" → "/0"

И так далее. Очень время затратно.

Как найти сразу все буквы латинского алфавита и удалить их? 
Пробовал через запятую, пробел, в скобка - не ищет. В ответах тоже не удалось найти информацию.

Answer (score 5):

При поиске используйте регулярку: `[a-zA-Z]`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно поставить плагин [TextFX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/). С ним намного проще будет работа. Про сами регулярки есть [дока](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @Abyx а без него работает?

Comment: @Abyx хорошо. Почему-то думал, что это плагин добавляет.

Comment: Спасибо! Но опять не получается. К сожалению, не могу прикрепить картинку. Replace All: 0 occurence replaced :( 

Т.е., он даже не ищет. Как будто не действует поиск. По одному символу - работает чётко.

Answer (score 0):

Заменить по регулярному выражению `[a-z]` на пустое. Указывать в обоих регистрах не требуется, т. к. в параметрах замены есть соответствующий флажок.

[image: скриншот]